# Redshift - Breaking number into 10 parts and finding which part does a number fall into

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

I am trying to break down a given number into 10 equal parts and then compare a row of numbers and see in which of the 10 parts they fall under.

```
ref_number, number_to_check
70, 34
70, 44
70, 14
70, 24
```

In the above data set, I would like to break 70 into 10 equal parts (in this case it would be 7,14,21, and so on till 70). Next I would like to see in which "part" does the value in column "number_to_check" fall into.

Output expected:

```
ref_number, number_to_check, part
70, 34, 5
70, 44, 7
70, 14, 2
70, 24, 4
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want arithmetic.  If I understand correctly:

```
select ceiling(number_to_check * 10.0 / ref_number)
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=f1f655b803ed76aefb281da23170d441) is a db<>fiddle (the fiddle happens to use Postgres).